# How can you condense a large OR statement in excel

Tags: excel

Some background: I am an intermediate excel user, I understand how to nest formulas and use macros, but I have never taken any classes or used VBA. For work I just run simple analysis, but I am actively trying to learn more about VBA so I can do more complex analysis.

Goal: I am trying to condense this or statement. It works fine but it is long, and I feel like there is a way to make shorter/less of a mess.

OR((G2=" Credit Memo - Customer Satisfaction", G2=" Credit Memo - Canceled Order", G2=" Commercial- Credit Memo", G2=" Credit Memo - Mfr Issue", H2=" Credit Memo - Customer Satisfaction", H2=" Credit Memo - Canceled Order", H2=" Commercial- Credit Memo", H2=" Credit Memo - Mfr Issue", I2=" Credit Memo - Customer Satisfaction", I2=" Credit Memo - Canceled Order", I2=" Commercial- Credit Memo", I2=" Credit Memo - Mfr Issue", J2=" Credit Memo - Customer Satisfaction", J2=" Credit Memo - Canceled Order", J2=" Commercial- Credit Memo", J2=" Credit Memo - Mfr Issue", K2=" Credit Memo - Customer Satisfaction", K2=" Credit Memo - Canceled Order", K2=" Commercial- Credit Memo", K2=" Credit Memo - Mfr Issue", L2=" Credit Memo - Customer Satisfaction", L2=" Credit Memo - Canceled Order", L2=" Commercial- Credit Memo", L2=" Credit Memo - Mfr Issue")

The raw data that I am using has data in columns A:G, with column G having anywhere between 1-6 job tags. I usually download the report and use text to columns to separate the job tags. In column M I want to write a function that tells me if one of the following job tags is in columns G:L
Credit Memo - Canceled Order
Commercial- Credit Memo
Credit Memo - Mfr Issue
Credit Memo - Customer Satisfaction

Answer (score 0):

This is a good case for using array formulas. Essentially, they work just like regular formulas, except that you use functions that normally work on scalars on arrays instead. To be more clear, instead of `IF(A1='BLAH'...` you can do `IF(A1:G1='BLAH'...`

Here, I set up a small example worksheet with data in A1:C5 with formulas located in column E and the list of lookup values in F1:F3. The following array formula then returns 1 where any of the lookup values was found in any of the cells in the current Ax:Gx range.

```
=MAX(IF(NOT(ISERROR(FIND($F$1:$F$3,A1:C1))), 1, 0))
```

To enable array formulas, you need to type `CTRL`+`SHIFT`+`ENTER` in the formula bar when the formula is ready. It should then display enclosed in curly braces like such:

```
{=MAX(IF(NOT(ISERROR(FIND($F$1:$F$3,A1:C1))), 1, 0))}
```

Comment: Another option: instead of the CSE formula, use SUMPRODUCT: something like `=SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH(G2,F$1:F$20)))>0` - which would compare a list of lookup values in `F$1:F$20` against the text in `G2`, and allow OP to not have to use text-to-columns.

Comment: My solution does not require using text to columns and does allot for using a list of lookup values in a single statement.

Comment: This solution does work on a row by row basis. The above formula needs to be copied and pasted for each row but will lookup on a range of rows which include the lookup values.

Comment: Eh. Just giving OP another option.

Answer (score 0):

Since your `OR` function returns `TRUE/FALSE` as a result, for an equivalent try:

```
=OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($P$1:$P$4,G2:L2)))
```

where `P1:P4` (or any range), contains the list of job tags.

*If you want to hard-code the job tags in the formula, you could use:*

```
=OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH({"Credit Memo - Canceled Order";"Commercial- Credit Memo";"Credit Memo - Mfr Issue";"Credit Memo - Customer Satisfaction"},G2:L2)))
```

*but for maintenance, you are better off storing the job  tags in a range, as in the first example.*